# Does Here have an API to collect annual average daily traffic on their road segments?

Tags: here-api, traffic

I am trying to construct a dataset including road links, their geometries, and information about the roads such as number of lanes, functional class, and average daily traffic.  I have been unable to determine whether Here has an API to retrieve something approximating average annual daily traffic for each road link.  Is it feasible to retrieve this data?

I've found an API to get general road link information which does not include traffic:
https://developer.here.com/documentation/platform-data/dev_guide/topics/quick-start-view-map-data.html

I've found an API to retrieve map tile images built from historic data (given a day of week and time of day) that shows traffic flow, but does not provide the underlying data:
https://developer.here.com/documentation/map-tile/dev_guide/topics/example-traffic.html

My desired result would be something structured as {road_link_id, annual_average_daily_traffic}, so that I can connect the link with other associated information.

Comment: This isn't really the place to ask questions about whether or not a product exists, why not just go on the Here website and look? If you're not sure, drop them an e-mail and ask. I would be very surprised if they have such a things as their data is GPS-derived from a static sample of vehicles so has little statistical validity for predicting AADT or other traffic count metrics. Mostly likley source for that data is the local transport authority.

Comment: Here's "Help" page directs to stackoverflow: https://developer.here.com/help  I was unable to determine whether a product exists by looking through the website.  I'm only considering Here because many local transportation authorities don't have AADT for local and private roads.

Comment: An interesting approach to customer support. Problem is SO posting guidelines say that the site is for specific programming questions so if it's related to how you're implementing the Here APIs and you can share your code you'll probably be ok, if it's a general enquiry like this one there's a good chance the question will get deleted.

Comment: I agree that SO isn't a good fit for this style of question and their redirect seems inappropriate in this instance. It appears Here also has a Slack channel, so I'm trying my question there as well.

Answer (score 1):

The HERE Traffic API is what you are looking for. It offers:

**Traffic Incident Data** - provides aggregated information about traffic incidents in XML or JSON, including the type and location of each traffic incident, status, start and end time, and other relevant data. This data is useful to dynamically optimize route calculations.

**Traffic Flow Data** - provides access to real-time traffic flow data in XML or JSON, including information on speed and congestion for the region(s) defined in each request. The API can also deliver additional data such as the geometry of the road segments in relation to the flow.

**Traffic Flow Availability** - allows client applications to access traffic flow information (excluding incidents) in an area, if available.

**Traffic Map Tile Overlays (Traffic Tiles)** - delivers pre-rendered map tile overlays with traffic information that you can readily display with your mapping application. You can request map tiles that show traffic data for a specific area.

See documentation: https://developer.here.com/documentation/traffic/dev_guide/topics/what-is.html